# Sending mail using nodemailer, need the steps

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, automated-tests, testcafe

I am new to `testcafe` and Node.js and I want to send mail using `nodemailer`. Can someone give me the steps? I tried few I am not sure if I am doing something incorrectly.

Here are the steps that  followed:

1. install nodemailer: `npm install nodemailer`
2. Create a Nodemailer transporter using either SMTP or some other transport mechanism
3. Set up message options (who sends what to whom)
4. Deliver the message object using the `sendMail()` method of your previously created transporter:

```js
var mailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = mailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.abc.email",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: "email@abc.com", //
    pass: "password" //
  }
});

// send mail with defined transport object
var mail = {
  from: "email@abc.com", // sender address
  to: "email@abc.com", // list of receivers
  subject: "hello", // Subject line
  text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
  html: "<b>Hello world?</b>" // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
  }

  transporter.close();
});
```

I have the following questions:

1. For SMTP do I need to install anything from npm?
2. Most of the examples in net shows Gmail, but I replace it with my company mail, I have considered here as `smtp.abc.com` do I need to do anything else?
3. I want to send mail from my company email, what different setting is needed for that?

Comment: Have you tried running your code and verifying if email sending works?

Comment: getting the below error
{ Error: queryA ESERVFAIL smtp.abc.email
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] 
  errno: 'ESERVFAIL',
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'smtp.abcemail',
  command: 'CONN' }

Comment: Have you replaced the `host` with the real SMPT host? `smtp.abc.email` is just an example, you have to create a real SMTP server using some external email services.

Comment: I was finally able to get the code run. i was not able to figure out my company server. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

> 1. For SMTP do I need to install anything from npm?

No. Only `nodemailer`

> 2. I want to send mail from my company email, what different setting is needed for that?

```js
import * as nodeMailer from "nodemailer";

const MAILER_CONFIG = Object.freeze({
    host: "smtp.mycompany.com",
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // true for 465 SMTP port, otherwise false
    auth: {
        user: "username",
        pass: "password"
    }
});

const MAIL_OPTIONS = Object.freeze({
    from: mailSender,
    to: mailReceiver,
    subject: mailSubject,
    text: mailBodyText,
    html: mailBodyHTML
});

const TRANSPORTER = Object.freeze(nodeMailer.createTransport(MAILER_CONFIG));

const mailSendingResult = await TRANSPORTER.sendMail(MAIL_OPTIONS);

TRANSPORTER.close();
```